# How to parse html tags in a string to jsx

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

We have a project which uses drupal as a CMS.we get some data in a string format.
Some of the strings contains html tags in them.
`<p>some text</p>` : this is a string.
As usual when we render it in our React component the string "some text" becomes `<p>some text</p>`.

My question is how to parse the string as a DOM element in jsx and also can apply styles to those tags like `<p>`, `<strong>`...

Is there a way we can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use html-react-parser, https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser

Comment: Yes, I used it and it works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

I found a very nice react package for the problem, where it solved everything and with the CSS targeting the child component I was able to change the styling.

> html-react-parser

just install it and use it like :

```
let someTextvariable: any = HTMLReactParser(props.information);
```

Thanks to everyone.